# How to draw ggplot with the data from the frame?

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, scatter-plot, ggplotly

I have gathered the data consisting of estimations of 2 means. I would like to draw ggplot (points connected with lines), where

- on the y axis there are values of means
- on there are iterations (from 1 to 10) ("iteracje")
- there would be 2 lines for 2 means which I'd color differently

I started like this, but I don't know why when I put the iterations on x axis, the mean is only one point. Below is how the data frame looks and my code. Thank you for help!

```
> frame
mu_1     mu_2 iteracje
1  0.9865904 7.005866        1
2  0.9865904 7.005866        2
3  0.9865904 7.005866        3
4  0.9865904 7.005866        4
5  0.9865904 7.005866        5
6  0.9865904 7.005866        6
7  0.9865904 7.005866        7
8  0.9865904 7.005866        8
9  0.9865904 7.005866        9
10 0.9865904 7.005866       10

 frame = data.frame(mu_1, mu_2,iteracje=1:10)
 ggplot(frame,aes(iteracje, mu_1))+geom_point(aes(mu_2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this. The key is reshaping data to long and then plot:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Code
frame %>% pivot_longer(-iteracje) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(iteracje),y=value,color=name,group=name))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
frame <- structure(list(mu_1 = c(0.9865904, 0.9865904, 0.9865904, 0.9865904, 
0.9865904, 0.9865904, 0.9865904, 0.9865904, 0.9865904, 0.9865904
), mu_2 = c(7.005866, 7.005866, 7.005866, 7.005866, 7.005866, 
7.005866, 7.005866, 7.005866, 7.005866, 7.005866), iteracje = 1:10), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```